# Importing functions in R

Tags: r, function, import

In Python we have chance to import a certain function from a library with a command "import *function* from *library* **as smth**. Do we have something similar in R? 
I know that we can call the function like "*library*::*function*()", my question mostly refers to the "as" part.

Comment: `x <- package::function` will assign `x` as `package::function`.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Just `library(smth)` to load the `smth-pkg then call function whatever its name ... (NOT `library::smth` unless you know for damned sure that there are no further calls to functions in that package) guessing that the downvotes on question is for evidence of not doing any effort at searching, just a guess, not my downvote. They are NOT libraries in R anyway, they are packages.

Answer (score 3):

It is not common and not necessary to do this in R. The assignment operator `<-` can be used to give a new name to an existing function. For example, one could define a function that does exactly the same as lubridate's, `year()` function with:

```
asYear <- lubridate::year
```

One could argue that, by doing so, the `year()` function has been "imported" from the `lubridate` package and that it is now called `asYear()`. In fact, the new function does just the same (which is no surprise, simply because it *is* the same):

```
asYear(Sys.Date())
#[1] 2016
```

So it is possible to construct an analogy to "from package import as", but it is not a good idea to do this. Here are a few reasons I can think of:

- Debugging a code where library functions have been renamed will be
  much more difficult.
- The documentation is not available for the renamed function. In this example, `?asYear` won't work, in contrast to `?lubridate::year` or `library(lubridate); help(year)`.
- The function is not only renamed but it is copied, which clutters the environment and is inefficient in terms of memory usage.
- The maintenance of the code becomes unnecessarily difficult. If another programmer (or the original programmer a few years later) looks at a code containing such a redefinition of a function, it will be harder for her or him to understand what this function is doing.

There are probably more reasons, but I hope that this is sufficient to discourage the use of such a construction. Different programming languages have different peculiarities, and as a programmer it is necessary to adapt to them. What is common in Python can be awkward in R, and vice versa.

A simple and commonly used way to handle such a standard situation in R is to use `library()` to load the entire namespace of the package containing the requested function:

```
library (lubridate)
year(Sys.Date())
```

However, one should be aware of possible namespace clashes, especially if many libraries are loaded simultaneously. Different functions could be defined with the same name in different packages. A well-known example thereof are the contrasting implementations of the `lag()` function in the `dplyr` and `stats` package. 
In such cases one can use the double colon operator `::` to resolve the namespace that should be addressed. This would be similar to the use of "from" in the case of "import", but such a specification would be needed each time the function is called.

```
lubridate::year(Sys.Date()) 
#[1] 2016
```

Comment: tidyverse and data.table like to have the same function names.